# PHP - SimpleXML xpath function to get value of particular node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xquery, simplexml

XML have entry like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<buildings  xmlns='<NS-URL-here>'>
    <building>
            <Address>           
                <commons:FullStreetAddress>1234 Forest Hills Dr</commons:FullStreetAddress>
                <commons:UnitNumber>LA - UNO</commons:UnitNumber>
                <commons:City>Coral Springs</commons:City>
                <commons:StateOrProvince>FL</commons:StateOrProvince>
                <commons:PostalCode>33065</commons:PostalCode>
                <commons:Country>US</commons:Country>
            </Address>
            .
            .
            .
            <Offices>
                <Office>
                    <Address>
                    <commons:FullStreetAddress>4567 City Hills Dr</commons:FullStreetAddress>
                <commons:UnitNumber>Office - UNO</commons:UnitNumber>
                <commons:City>Transels Springs</commons:City>
                <commons:StateOrProvince>FL</commons:StateOrProvince>
                <commons:PostalCode>75045</commons:PostalCode>
                <commons:Country>US</commons:Country>
                </Address>
            </Office>
            </Offices>
    </building>
 ...
...
...

    </buildings>
```

I need to fecth FullStreetAddress from Building Address. Not from Office address. 
I used below code to fetch and it returns office full address if building full address not present.

How do i fetch Full address from building Address node only.

My code:

```
$building_address = $listing_node->xpath("//commons:FullStreetAddress");
```

Comment: You need to make your XPath expression more specific. The `child` axis is of particular interest here.

Comment: It looks like /buildings/building/Address/commons:FullStreetAddress is what you need (as long as you've declared the relevant namespaces). Be aware //anything will try and match on every node in the document, so is usually bad practice.

Comment: Try this: $building_address = $listing_node->xpath("//building/Address/commons:FullStreetAddress");

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I found answer for my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found answer

Instead of

```
$building_address = $listing_node->xpath("//commons:FullStreetAddress");
```

(Above one is for search from the XML root Node to throughout the entire node.)

We should use

```
$building_address = $listing_node->Address->xpath("commons:FullStreetAddress");
```

This one is for searching inside the particular node.